# Após seleção com Select2, como preencher automaticamente campos do formulário?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json, jquery-select2

Estou criando um formulário que possui um campo que o usuário irá digitar o nome da empresa e o Select2 irá realizar uma busca no BD e retornar o nome da empresa para o campo, exemplo na imagem abaixo:

[image: select2]

Script no HTML:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {  
      $('#nome_pj').select2({
        placeholder: "Digite o nome da empresa",
        ajax: {         
            url: 'autosuggest_busca_pessoajuridica.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            quietMillis: 50,
            data: function (term) {
                return {
                    term: term
                };
            },
            results: function (data) {
                var results = [];                   
                $.each(data, function(index, item){
                    results.push({
                        text: item.nome_pj,
                        id: item.nome_pj
                    });
                });
                return {results: results};
            }
          }
       });
     });
```

Código do Select2 (`autosuggest_busca_pessoajuridica.php`) para realizar a busca no BD:

```
<?php

include("lib/config.php");
include("lib/util.php");

$con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME) or die("Error " . mysqli_error($con));

function destacaTexto($highlite,$string){
    return str_ireplace($highlite,"<b>".$highlite."</b>",$string);
}

//Para a busca do auto completar
$input  = (isset($_GET['term']))? htmlspecialchars($_GET['term']) :null;

$input = utf8_decode($input);

if ($input!=''){
$data = array();

function toUtf8(&$item, $key) {
    $item = iconv("iso-8859-1","utf-8",$item);
}

$query = "SELECT id_feap_pj, tipo_pj, cnpj, nome_pj, endereco_pj, num_end_pj, compl_end_pj, bairro_end_pj, cep_pj, id_mun, uf_pj, telefone_pj, email_pj, nome_representante_pj, cpf_representante_pj, data_cadastro_pj, data_alteracao_pj, id_user 
          FROM feap_pj
          WHERE nome_pj LIKE '%$input%' ";

$result = $con->query($query);  

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    array_walk($row, 'toUtf8');

    extract($row);

    $json = array();
    $json['id_feap_pj'] = $id_feap_pj;
    $json['tipo_pj'] = $tipo_pj;
    $json['cnpj'] = $cnpj;
    $json['nome_pj'] = $nome_pj;
    $json['endereco_pj'] = $endereco_pj;
    $json['num_end_pj'] = $num_end_pj;
    $json['compl_end_pj'] = $compl_end_pj;
    $json['bairro_end_pj'] = $bairro_end_pj;
    $json['cep_pj'] = $cep_pj;
    $json['id_mun'] = $id_mun;
    $json['uf_pj'] = $uf_pj;
    $json['telefone_pj'] = $telefone_pj;
    $json['email_pj'] = $email_pj;
    $data[] = $json;
}

header("Content-type: application/json");
echo json_encode($data);
}

?>
```

O Select2 funciona normalmente e consegue fazer a busca no BD para retornar o nome da empresa.

Eu gostaria que assim que eu selecionar o nome da empresa, todas as outras informações sejam preenchidas automaticamente, com base nos valores contidos no BD e retorne nos campos do formulário. Como faço isso através do Select2?

Comment: Eu não sei o que é esse Select2, um plugin ou algo próprio, mas seu eu tivesse que imaginar uma solução eu diria que você deve disparar uma rotina AJAX (óbvio) no jQuery.click() dos elementos desse campo. Mas, como eu não sei se esse componente adiciona algo clicável ao elemento onde as sugestões aparecem (como links, por exemplo) eu sugeriria que você disparasse tal rotina no jQuery.blur() do campo. Assim você clicaria no elemento normalmente, o tal do Select2 preencheria o campo com aquilo que foi retornado como sugestão e quando o campo perdesse o foco outra coisa diferente aconteceria.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use o método `change` e com o id que é o value selecionado no Select2 faça uma chamada ajax para pegar todos os dados que você precisa e depois popular os campos com o método `html`

```
$('#nome_pj').select2({
            ...
}).change(function () {
     var id = $(this).val();

     $.ajax({
        ...
        success: function(data){
             $('#campo').html(data.Nome);
             ...
        }
     });

});
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda Gustavo.

Perdoe minha ignorância em Ajax, mas poderia me citar um exemplo, tentei desta forma e não consegui.

.change(function () { 
     var id = $(this).val(); 

        $.ajax({ 
           var cnpj = $("input[name='cnpj']"); 
          
           success: function(data){
            $('#cpnj').html(data.cpnj); 
           } 
         }); 
       });

Comment: essa chamada ajax seria a função do jquery: $.ajax({ url: 'url do request', data: {'Parametro 1': 'Valor' }, success: function(){} }); para mais informações veja essa parte da API: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: obrigado gustavo, ajudou bastante !

Answer (score 0):

Encontrei também uma outra forma de resolver, não ficou nada bonito/elegante o código mas funciona.

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

//Preenchimento automatico depois de selecionado no autocompletar do campo nome 
$(document).ready(function() {

    //Autocompletar para seleção de nome dos clientes
    $('#nome_pj').select2({

        placeholder: "Digite o nome do produtor rural",
        ajax: {         
            url: 'autosuggest_busca_pessoajuridica.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            quietMillis: 50,
            data: function (term) {
                return {
                    term: term
                };
            },
            results: function (data) {
                var results = [];                   
                $.each(data, function(index, item){
                    results.push({
                        text: item.nome_pj,
                        id: item.nome_pj,
                        cnpj: item.cnpj,
                        endereco_pj: item.endereco_pj,
                        num_end_pj: item.num_end_pj,
                        compl_end_pj: item.compl_end_pj,
                        bairro_end_pj: item.bairro_end_pj,
                        cep_pj: item.cep_pj,
                        id_mun: item.municipio,
                        uf_pj: item.estado,
                        telefone_pj: item.telefone_pj,
                        email_pj: item.email_pj,
                        nome_representante_pj: item.nome_representante_pj,
                        cpf_representante_pj: item.cpf_representante_pj

                    });
                });                 
                return {results: results};
            }
        },
    }).on("change", preencheFormulario); 

    function preencheFormulario(el) {           
        var data = $(el.target).select2('data');
        var cnpj = data.cnpj;
        var cnpjInput = document.getElementById('cnpj');
        cnpjInput.value = cnpj;
        var endereco_pj = data.endereco_pj;         
        var enderecopjInput = document.getElementById('endereco_pj');
        enderecopjInput.value = endereco_pj;
        var num_end_pj = data.num_end_pj;
        var numendpjInput = document.getElementById('num_end_pj');
        numendpjInput.value = num_end_pj;
        var compl_end_pj = data.compl_end_pj;
        var complendpjInput = document.getElementById('compl_end_pj');
        complendpjInput.value = compl_end_pj;
        var bairro_end_pj = data.bairro_end_pj;
        var bairroendpjInput = document.getElementById('bairro_end_pj');
        bairroendpjInput.value = bairro_end_pj;
        var cep_pj = data.cep_pj;
        var ceppjInput = document.getElementById('cep_pj');
        ceppjInput.value = cep_pj;
        var id_mun = data.id_mun;
        var idmunInput = document.getElementById('id_mun');
        idmunInput.value = id_mun;
        var uf_pj = data.uf_pj;
        var ufpjInput = document.getElementById('uf_pj');
        ufpjInput.value = uf_pj; 
        var telefone_pj = data.telefone_pj;
        var telefonepjInput = document.getElementById('telefone_pj');
        telefonepjInput.value = telefone_pj;
        var email_pj = data.email_pj;
        var emailpjInput = document.getElementById('email_pj');
        emailpjInput.value = email_pj;
        var nome_representante_pj = data.nome_representante_pj;
        var nomerepresentantepjInput = document.getElementById('nome_representante_pj');
        nomerepresentantepjInput.value = nome_representante_pj;
        var cpf_representante_pj = data.cpf_representante_pj;
        var cpfrepresentantepjInput = document.getElementById('cpf_representante_pj');
        cpfrepresentantepjInput.value = cpf_representante_pj;
    }   
});

</script>
```